# Memory leak warning due to websocket and stomp in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I am using Stomp in a Spring Boot app where I am getting memory leak warning after adding below code. How to resolve it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/our-websocket")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new UserHandshakeHandler())
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

I am running this in my local. After terminating the app,
I am getting a warning -- The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MessageBroker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.